# Token based basic Authentication in tornado python

Tags: python, tornado

I dont want to give access of any Api's without authentication, i want to know how to check basic token and give access in tornado framework please suggest me any example.

Comment: [This example has quite good and correct approach](https://github.com/douglaslira/tornado-jwt/blob/master/app/handlers/auth.py)

Comment: Thanks! @Fian, but i have different scenario, I have get basic authorisation from client it has encoded with key so how to decode in our tornado code i am not able to decode. please give me solution of any?